# How to list out my contact list in APPLOZIC in PHP(for web chatting)?

Tags: php, api, livechat, applozic

I want to add my contact list in **Applozic** API for chatting in PHP application.

There are no any option to **Add New Contact**.

Please help me if anyone knows.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in onInit for loading contacts:

```
$applozic.fn.applozic('loadContacts', 
                          {"contacts": [{"userId": "USER_1", "displayName": "Devashish",
                          "imageLink": "https://www.applozic.com/resources/images/applozic_icon.png", // image url(optional)
                          "imageData" :"Base64 encoded image data"  // or image data (optional)
                          },
                          {"userId": "USER_2", "displayName": "Adarsh",
                           "imageLink": "https://www.applozic.com/resources/images/applozic_icon.png", // image url(optional)
                           "imageData" :"Base64 encoded image data"  // or image data (optional)
                           },
                          {"userId": "USER_3", "displayName": "Shanki",
                          "imageLink": "https://www.applozic.com/resources/images/applozic_icon.png", // image url(optional)
                          "imageData" :"Base64 encoded image data"  // or image data (optional)
                          }
                        ]
         });
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devashishmamgain/9pobaenb/) to load contacts in Applozic Chat plugin.

https://www.applozic.com/docs/web-chat-plugin.html#step-4-populate-contact-list

For full screen view layout demo, view the source of
https://www.applozic.com/docs/chat-examples/web.html